# Welcome to GenAI Stack Exchange! ("Limited Private Beta")

Tags: discussion, private-beta

If someone might want to read the Welcome message to the "limited private beta" again without using incognito mode / delete cookies, here is its content.

> ## Welcome to GenAI Stack Exchange!
>
> *Q&A for GenAI enthusiasts and practitioners and those interested in learning more about using GenAI tools*
>
> ### We need your help
>
> This site is currently in a **limited private beta**. We need your help to ask and answer interesting questions to test whether this site has enough participation to move into public beta. Vote for your favorites to encourage more like it!
>
> ### New site doesn’t necessarily mean “beginner” questions
>
> We’ve gathered a group of experts and enthusiasts, so ask and answer the types of question YOU would like to see on this site. Questions should be specific and answerable — we are building a library of definitive questions and answers that others might encounter in their day to day work or study. Of course, questions from beginners are welcome too.
>
> When folks come to this site for the first time, we want the front page to reflect the types of questions YOU would want to see asked on a site like this.
>
> The site went into private beta on July 17, 2023 and will undergo evaluation by the Community Team for the next six months to determine whether it will stay open. The site will have transitioned to a public beta on July 25th.
>
> Welcome!

P.S. GenAI Stack Exchange is not limited by having a list of allowed users, but please do not invite all your friends yet as the site hasn't enough questions, and a lot of stuff is too chaotic for some souls. I suggest waiting for the announcement of the launch of the **Public Beta**.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to see on the Ask-Question-page and on a close-reason shown on top of the flat / vote-to-close dialog the following:

> Questions should be specific and answerable — we are building a library of definitive questions and answers that others might encounter in their day to day work or study.

The part of beginner to the site topic and scope questions should be included too, but "beginner" should not be confused with "any question is allowed".

Related

- [Add a link to "What is on-topic on GenAI SE?" to the Help Center homepage](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/12)