# Add a link to "What is on-topic on GenAI SE?" to the Help Center homepage

Tags: feature-request, help-center, help-center-homepage

I just found a question with one close vote. I click on the Close (1) link, and this show me

[image: You've earned the close an reopen votes]

Once I click the *Got it** button, the Close dialog that the close reason for having one vote is:

> **A community-specific reason** 1
> This question doesn’t meet a GenAI Stack Exchange guideline.

Clicking on this reason shows that the custom close reason with one vote is

> This question does not appear to be about GenAI, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://genai.stackexchange.com/home).

The help center link points to the help center home.  Considering this, the help center homepage (diamond users could do this) should be edited.

The initial version might include a link to [What is on-topic on GenAI SE?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/12). This question should be improved to tell people arriving from the help center GenAI SE scope is a work in progress. Most people looking at the help center will likely do it because of having one question closed during the "limited private beta".