# Is it okay to ask for examples of genAI usage and output?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

There are likely thousands of genAIs around nowadays.  Some require payment.  Some are not universally accessible.  I think would be nice to get examples of realistic usage of these sites, and not rely on advertisements (who knows how reliable they are).

I'm imagining questions like:

- What are some examples of GPT-4 analyzing humor in user images?
- What does a typical Midjourney workflow look like?
- What are some good and bad examples of having a [Replika](https://replika.com/) AI companion?
- What examples highlight the difference between Bard and ChatGPT?
- What are some examples where genAI has refused to do something completely reasonable?
- How do Chinese-language genAIs respond to politically sensitive topics, e.g. Taiwan?

**Question**: Is it okay to ask for examples of genAI usage and output?

Comment: There is a related tag, so far without tag wiki, [tag:examples].

Answer (score 2):

As of the time of writing this answer, there are 3 questions in [examples](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples) tag. [One](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/103/what-are-some-examples-of-bing-being-rude) is closed as opinion-based. [Another one](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/142/how-we-migrate-database-from-one-cloud-to-aonther), unrelated to this matter, is closed as off-topic. [The last one](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/192/what-is-the-hello-world-of-image-generation) is still open even though I think it should be closed as opinion-based as well. Plus, there are a list of the imagined example questions, which I still think that some of them are going to be closed as opinion-based if they are ever posted.

I would like to refer to [a comment from Wicket](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/103/what-are-some-examples-of-bing-being-rude#comment180_103) and [a comment from V2Blast](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/103/what-are-some-examples-of-bing-being-rude#comment239_103) from one of the questions above that I also agree to both of these comments. Please read those first.

According to the [current scope](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/28), asking for a list of resources/tools is off-topic. What the asker can do to prevent such situation is to rephrase the question into asking something specific while also ask for example(s) of such topic. Let's do an example from one of your listed questions.

> What examples highlight the difference between Bard and ChatGPT?

As it is currently written, this question asks for examples that can be considered opinion-based, and closed accordingly. Let me rephrase it a bit so that the question can be on-topic. Something like

> What is the difference between Bard and ChatGPT?

and in the body of the question, just ask for the answers to include some examples if possible. This will make it a fact-based question.

So, as for the question.

> Is it okay to ask for examples of genAI usage and output?

I would say it is not okay to ask just for the examples alone of anything. It would be great that a question asks something specific within the scope (even if we are still defining the scope) and request for some examples of that matter.

Comment: I agree with this position as well as Wicket and V2Blast's comments. I think this is the best way and ensure that the asker is putting a little effort and that their questions that might be looking for examples are valuable to others.

Answer (score 1):

While we still have a lot of work on how to prevent post bans and other "penalties" for people who make an effort to contribute with high-quality questions while the site attributes like name, blurb, scope and workings are still being discussed and unclear, I encourage you to choose one of these "one liner" questions included in this meta question and do your best to transform it into a real high-quality question and post it GenAI SE.

One way we might collaborate in this process is to use a particular tag, i.e, [question-sandbox](/questions/tagged/question-sandbox), adding the guidelines to collaborate on the meta-question and providing a tentative real question as an answer marked as a community wiki.

The instructions should explain the tone and quality standards to be explored and show the tentative / community wiki should be discussed.

Related

- [Welcome to GenAI Stack Exchange! ("Limited Private Beta")](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/12)
- [What are the best practices to have debates in GenAI Meta?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/12)

Comment: Okay [here](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/103/26)'s one example.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Thanks. So far, there is a related tag without tag wiki, [tag:examples]. Two questions are closed, and one question posted 15 hours ago, is still open. I think that this is a good exercise to help us to define the site scope.