# We are still looking to define the tone and quality standards of GenAI SE among other critical attributes

Tags: discussion

We have embarked on a journey into the unknown aboard an old ship, the public Q&A platform.

Since 2010, almost all the public platform new sites have started with new site proposals on Area 51 and followed site creation stages "private beta", "public beta". This site follows an ongoing loosely defined experimental site creation process.

Terms like "private beta" and "public beta" are fine for explaining how things are handled in this experimental process **by contrasting** it with how similar things are done in the standard process. Still, we must improve how we communicate the current workings and immediate priorities, like defining this community's tone and quality standards for our questions and answers.

Let's adapt the welcome to the limited private beta that was shown to new visitors to encourage people to contribute with high-quality questions that help us have rich conversations about the critical attributes of this community, including the profile of subject matter experts that we would like that fine this community attractive to come to share their wisdom and join to the quest to have a library of high-quality questions and answer if that is still one of the things that make SO and Stack Exchange communities different from other places on the Web.

Related

- [Welcome to GenAI Stack Exchange! ("Limited Private Beta")](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/12)